# How to make header and logo responsive?(Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Ok,i made header and logo :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test2.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>


    <div class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
     <div class="container-fluid">

      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button class="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/test1.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
      </div>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>

 </div>
</div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and CSS:

```
.navbar-nav {
min-height: 110px;
}

.navbar-brand img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

The question is how to my logo image be responsive as I resize the browser and how to header be responsive(when decrease size)? As you can see I put height in external CSS file 110px,and now I want to logo enter inside header(like in full size browser) when resize into small screens. I hope you get it

Comment: Sorry but would you mind clarifying. Do you mean you want the logo to appear inside the mobile menu when you resize the page or that you want the image size to be responsive?

Comment: Image size to be responsive(to be in the same position in header as far as in regular browser size)

Comment: so you just want the image to fit inside the header at all times?

Comment: Yes, i want that.

Comment: You need to use media-queries to be able to do so, more in the docs: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-media-queries

Answer (score 2):

To keep your header image inside your header at all times you can simply apply `max-height: 100%;` to your image. This will stop it from overflowing its container. Here is an example: **https://jsfiddle.net/rktr4q5v/1/**

You can see that the images are both quite small. This is because the class navbar-brand has a height of 50px applied. If you remove this then your images will expand to their original width but remain inside the navbar. Here is an example of this: **https://jsfiddle.net/rktr4q5v/2/**

If you need to do specific size styling for your logos then you will need to use media queries to change the size of your logo at different screen widths. The documentation for this can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) and a beginners [guide can be found here](https://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/)

Answer (score 1):

I have also fixed some of your mistakes. You can refer this.

Adjust your Logo Size in navbar-brand style tag. If requires

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test2.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
     <div class="container-fluid">

      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/34950/pexels-photo.jpg" class="img-responsive img-rounded" style="max-height: 40px; margin-top: -15%;"></a>
      </div>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-right">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   </div>
</div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```